# TC (Traffic control) and trickle: apply different bandwidth to (multiple requests) same IP or URL during upload and download

Tags: tc, traffic-shaping

I have some files of different sizes which I needed to send to Azure blob storage and I am using Azure IOT SDKs to achieve that.Now I have different types of file size ( from 50 MB to 5 GB) and have to sent them to blob storage within a particular amount of time. From that I can calculate how much bandwidth I have to give for file upload.

But for each of the occasions I am using the same URL for sending the data to cloud storage. Then how should I assign different bandwidth to each file upload process considered I already know the file sizes, time allocated to it and how much bandwidth I have to allocate.

I have gone through TC and Trickle to achieve this type of scenario but unable to find a solution where I can set different speeds to same end point URL or IP address based on some constraints(here file size).

It will be very much helpful if someone provide some link or suggest something how to achieve this.

Thank you.

Attaching the links : https://www.linux.com/blog/tc-show-manipulate-traffic-control-settingshttp://www.tuxradar.com/content/control-your-bandwidth-trickle